# error on handler.postDelayed (new Runnable () {

Tags: postdelayed

I am a novice programmer on android studio, I want to know why does the 
delay function does an error on `handler.postDelayed (new Runnable(){` do I have to import any library?  and what is the shortcut key for `:@override...`" whenever I does a code. thanks.

heres the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed (new Runnable(){
        @.
        public void run() {
             msg();

        }
    },500);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

sry i write it as an answer cause i cant post comments yet but can you post the exact error?
i'm pretty sure you should write

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements runnable {
```

but thats just an educated guess since I dont know whats the exact error you are getting.